# How to loop through List containig another list with java resultset

Tags: java

I have a function written in pl/sql that I call from a java web service. The response contains a list of values and one of the values is actually another list. I have no problem to print the values from the list(the parents) with  while(rs.next()) but I cannot print the values from the nested list(the children). Can somebody give me an example how to do that again with while(rs.next())? Thank you.

Comment: Can you make use of `instanceof`, and check if element is element, or another list?

Comment: You should maybe do recursion to get that one

Comment: If you tried to implement that please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value as a object the cast it to you desired  data type . Here is an example of List.

```
List<Account> a = (List<Account>) rs.getObject(8, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer. It's always a good idea to put code in a code block by indenting each line with four spaces.